# How to seed to test database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I can successfully seed records to my normal database. Now I am focusing on tests and the first step is to add 'test database'.
How can I seed to that specific database other than the normal database?

```
    `<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
     <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>
    <!-- <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
    <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
    <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>`
```

Above is my  phpunit configuration file, I also have env.testing file holding my testing configurations.
I already have daatabase called `database_testing` which is up

Comment: on copy your `.env` and rename to `.env.testing` , the change the `DB_DATABASE` for `database_testing `. don't forget to change the `APP_ENV=testing`

Comment: Thank you @francisco, then when  migrations/seeding, is there any other way other than `php artisan migrate --env=testing` `php artisan db:seed --env=testing`

Comment: for tests, you just need the `php artisan test`, in each test the bd will refresh with the trait `RefreshDatabase`.

Comment: Got it,Thank you @francisco

Comment: The `RefreshDatabase` trait just ensures the migrations are re-run before each test. You still need to seed the database. See the accepted answer in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Copy your `.env` and rename to `.env.testing`. Change:

```
DB_DATABASE=database_testing
APP_ENV=testing
```

Inside the new `.env.testing` file.

Answer (score -1):

on your .env file, change the name of database which you want to launch seed again:

```
DB_DATABASE=your_db_name
```

if not in local environment, change also the name of actual environment :

```
APP_ENV=actual_env_name
```

save modifications and enter command to allow use new env data :

```
php artisan config:cache
```